# SQLite - Database minus list of values

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am working on project where I need to load data from local mobile DB(SQLite) to UI in meanwhile load data from server and when data download is finished insert the data from server to the database and update UI. I searching for way to download data from server and instead of delete all data in database and insert the new valid data just find the changes and "update" database. Is there some correct way to do this. I am working with SQLite database on Android phone.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite isn't an online database meant to be ran on a server.

There aren't any free SQL Server options that I know of, but the NoSQL options include Firebase Realtime Database, Firebase Cloud Firestore, Realm Platform, Couchbase Mobile, Parse Server, etc...

Each of the listed options allow you to listen **only** to changes in the data. SQLite does not provide this option itself.

Comment: Maybe my explanation was inaccurate. I have to load data from local mobile database first and in the meanwhile download data from server API and when the data are downloaded then I update the database.

Comment: Still, all listed options are mobile-first databases. They store data offline, then sync when network becomes available. Again, SQLite does **not** provide these features